# variant variable interaction with a non-variant type

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I'm trying to solve the following problem. I have a vector (it's a custom structure actually, but a vector is a good enough substitute for this issue) of pointers to a custom class `A`. Class `A` can actually store either a `type_a` pointer or a `type_b` pointer (these types are quite different and are not related to each other). Right now that's implemented by keeping both, setting them to `NULL` and then having a bunch of `if/else` statements later on to check which type it is and perform appropriate action.

```
class A {
public:
  A() : p1(NULL), p2(NULL) {}

  type_a * p1;
  type_b * p2;
};

std::vector<A *> v;

...

if (v[0]->p1 != NULL) { /* do this */ }
else if (v[0]->p2 != NULL) { /* do that */ }
```

I plan to add more pointers to class `A`, and so the above is starting to become a hassle. The solution that I'm currently trying to make work is using `boost::variant` instead, to have:

```
class A {
public:
  boost::variant<type_a*, type_b*> p;
};
```

The problem I have encountered though, is that one of my actions involves calling a function that would assign some values to a variable depending on what type of `p` I have. This is what it is now and the appropriate `process_stuff` function is called inside one of the above `if/else` statements:

```
class B { /*...*/ };

void process_stuff(type_a * p, B * b) {
  b->m_var = p->fn1();
}

void process_stuff(type_b * p, B * b) {
  b->m_var = p->fn2();
}
```

I can't get this to work with `boost::static_visitor` since (as far as I understand) I can't have a non-variant type as an argument in binary visitation, nor can I have a non-const `operator()` to make the second variable a member of the visitor class and modify that inside `operator()` with unary visitation. So I'm confused how to convert the above `process_stuff` function to play along with `boost::variant`.

Btw I'm not attached to `boost::variant` and would take other solutions.

Comment: Short answer: unless you can unify the types somehow, any way you do a heterogeneous collection, it's probably going to be ugly and clumsy.

Comment: I can't unify the types unfortunately. I think it all would've worked quite well if I could e.g. have a non-const `operator()` in `static_visitor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need a stateful visitor. I'm typing this from a vague memory of exactly what visitors look like, but you should be able to fix any mistakes I make.

```
class process_stuff_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<void> {
  B* m_b;

public:
  process_stuff_visitor(B* b) : m_b(b) {}
  void visit(type_a* a) const { m_b->m_var = a->fn1(); }
  void visit(type_b* b) const { m_b->m_var = b->fn2(); }
};
// actual processing:
boost::apply_visitor(v[0], process_stuff_visitor(the_b));
```

Alternatively since you assign to the same member of B, you could just extract the value-generating part.

```
struct generate_stuff_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<TypeOfMVar> {
  TypeOfMVar visit(type_a* a) const { return a->fn1(); }
  TypeOfMVar visit(type_b* b) const { return b->fn2(); }
};
the_b->m_var = boost::apply_visitor(v[0], generate_stuff_visitor());
```

Answer (score 0):

A very general object-oriented way of doing what you want to do (if I understand you correctly) is to create a virtual base class for types a and b (and any further types you want) which defines a pure virtual method.  This method will return something different for each type (for example, type_b::method could return 'b', while type_a::method could return 'a'), so when you call the method on your unspecified type, you will be told what type it is.

From there, you can use the return value of the identifying method to be the subject of a switch statement, or some other conventional control structure to invoke the correct behavior.

Comment: Thanks, but `type_a` and `type_b` are "god-given", so I have no control over them.

Comment: Ah, in which case I would agree with Jerry Coffin's assessment of the situation.